# Possibilidade de arrastar um formulário com o mouse quando sua barra de títulos foi ocultada

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com um problema! Quando tento mover o meu programa para algum outro sitio do ecrã, não consigo, ele parece estar fixado. Alguém sabe como resolver?

@PS: Já tentei este código fornecido pelo Roberto e não funcionou.

```
Public Class Form1
Private WM_NCHITTEST As Integer = &H84
Private HTCLIENT As Integer = &H1
Private HTCAPTION As Integer = &H2

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)

    Select Case m.Msg
        Case WM_NCHITTEST
            If m.Result = New IntPtr(HTCLIENT) Then
                m.Result = New IntPtr(HTCAPTION)
            End If
    End Select
```

A barra de títulos do formulário foi retirada para que fosse usado um desenho personalizado em seu lugar de modo que o recurso de arrastar o formuláro clicando em sua barra de títulos foi perdida.

Código Form1.Designer.vb :

```
    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container
        Me.header = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel
        Me.PictureBox10 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        Me.PictureBox8 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        Me.PictureBox3 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        Me.body = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel
        Me.PictureBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        Me.Label7 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.Label6 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.PictureBox9 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        Me.Label5 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.Label4 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.Label3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.PictureBox7 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        Me.PictureBox6 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        Me.PictureBox5 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        Me.PictureBox4 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        Me.PictureBox2 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        Me.bemvindo = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.ToolTip1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(Me.components)
        Me.ErrorProvider1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider(Me.components)
        Me.Label8 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.header.SuspendLayout()
        CType(Me.PictureBox10, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox8, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox3, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.body.SuspendLayout()
        CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox9, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox7, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox6, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox5, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox4, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox2, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.ErrorProvider1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'header
        '
        Me.header.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(51, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(153, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(204, Byte), Integer))
        Me.header.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.header.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox10)
        Me.header.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox8)
        Me.header.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox3)
        Me.header.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top
        Me.header.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.header.Name = "header"
        Me.header.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(575, 46)
        Me.header.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'PictureBox10
        '
        Me.PictureBox10.Image = Global.AssistenteFdF.My.Resources.Resources.hruonXC
        Me.PictureBox10.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(506, 3)
        Me.PictureBox10.Name = "PictureBox10"
        Me.PictureBox10.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(34, 35)
        Me.PictureBox10.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        Me.PictureBox10.TabIndex = 2
        Me.PictureBox10.TabStop = False
        '
        'PictureBox8
        '
        Me.PictureBox8.Image = Global.AssistenteFdF.My.Resources.Resources.vdc7y0T
        Me.PictureBox8.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(532, 4)
        Me.PictureBox8.Name = "PictureBox8"
        Me.PictureBox8.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(34, 35)
        Me.PictureBox8.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        Me.PictureBox8.TabIndex = 1
        Me.PictureBox8.TabStop = False
        '
        'PictureBox3
        '
        Me.PictureBox3.Image = Global.AssistenteFdF.My.Resources.Resources.INS1aq9
        Me.PictureBox3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(11, 8)
        Me.PictureBox3.Name = "PictureBox3"
        Me.PictureBox3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(316, 34)
        Me.PictureBox3.TabIndex = 0
        Me.PictureBox3.TabStop = False
        '
        'body
        '
        Me.body.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.body.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.Label8)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox1)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.Label7)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.Label6)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox9)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.Label5)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.Label4)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.Label3)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.Label2)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox7)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox6)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox5)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox4)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox2)
        Me.body.Controls.Add(Me.bemvindo)
        Me.body.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.body.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 46)
        Me.body.Name = "body"
        Me.body.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(575, 311)
        Me.body.TabIndex = 1
        '
        'PictureBox1
        '
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = Global.AssistenteFdF.My.Resources.Resources.sl6Iv9x
        Me.PictureBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(408, 207)
        Me.PictureBox1.Name = "PictureBox1"
        Me.PictureBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(158, 100)
        Me.PictureBox1.TabIndex = 15
        Me.PictureBox1.TabStop = False
        '
        'Label7
        '
        Me.Label7.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label7.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial Narrow", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label7.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(2, 274)
        Me.Label7.Name = "Label7"
        Me.Label7.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(355, 20)
        Me.Label7.TabIndex = 14
        Me.Label7.Text = "Desenvolvido pela equipe de suporte Forumeiros © 2015" & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)
        '
        'Label6
        '
        Me.Label6.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label6.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label6.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(437, 145)
        Me.Label6.Name = "Label6"
        Me.Label6.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(71, 28)
        Me.Label6.TabIndex = 13
        Me.Label6.Text = "Mensagens" & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10) & "pré-definidas"
        Me.Label6.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        '
        'PictureBox9
        '
        Me.PictureBox9.Image = Global.AssistenteFdF.My.Resources.Resources.Done2
        Me.PictureBox9.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(447, 81)
        Me.PictureBox9.Name = "PictureBox9"
        Me.PictureBox9.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(57, 61)
        Me.PictureBox9.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        Me.PictureBox9.TabIndex = 12
        Me.PictureBox9.TabStop = False
        Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.PictureBox9, "Mensagens pré-definidas")
        '
        'Label5
        '
        Me.Label5.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label5.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(377, 145)
        Me.Label5.Name = "Label5"
        Me.Label5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(42, 28)
        Me.Label5.TabIndex = 11
        Me.Label5.Text = "Mover" & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10) & "tópicos"
        Me.Label5.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        '
        'Label4
        '
        Me.Label4.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label4.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(289, 145)
        Me.Label4.Name = "Label4"
        Me.Label4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(67, 28)
        Me.Label4.TabIndex = 10
        Me.Label4.Text = "Visualizador" & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10) & "HTML"
        Me.Label4.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        '
        'Label3
        '
        Me.Label3.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label3.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(213, 145)
        Me.Label3.Name = "Label3"
        Me.Label3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(65, 42)
        Me.Label3.TabIndex = 9
        Me.Label3.Text = "Perguntas e" & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10) & "respostas" & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10) & "frequentes"
        Me.Label3.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        '
        'Label2
        '
        Me.Label2.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label2.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(139, 145)
        Me.Label2.Name = "Label2"
        Me.Label2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(64, 28)
        Me.Label2.TabIndex = 8
        Me.Label2.Text = "MP de" & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10) & "advertência"
        Me.Label2.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(59, 145)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(66, 28)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 7
        Me.Label1.Text = "Mensagens " & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10) & "moderativas"
        Me.Label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        '
        'PictureBox7
        '
        Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(Me.PictureBox7, "[ERRO] Função indisponivel")
        Me.ErrorProvider1.SetIconAlignment(Me.PictureBox7, System.Windows.Forms.ErrorIconAlignment.BottomRight)
        Me.ErrorProvider1.SetIconPadding(Me.PictureBox7, -15)
        Me.PictureBox7.Image = Global.AssistenteFdF.My.Resources.Resources.folder_move_icon
        Me.PictureBox7.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(371, 81)
        Me.PictureBox7.Name = "PictureBox7"
        Me.PictureBox7.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(57, 61)
        Me.PictureBox7.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        Me.PictureBox7.TabIndex = 5
        Me.PictureBox7.TabStop = False
        Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.PictureBox7, "Mover tópicos (função indisponível)")
        '
        'PictureBox6
        '
        Me.PictureBox6.Image = Global.AssistenteFdF.My.Resources.Resources.HTML_File_Extension
        Me.PictureBox6.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(294, 81)
        Me.PictureBox6.Name = "PictureBox6"
        Me.PictureBox6.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(57, 61)
        Me.PictureBox6.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        Me.PictureBox6.TabIndex = 4
        Me.PictureBox6.TabStop = False
        Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.PictureBox6, "Visualizador HTML")
        '
        'PictureBox5
        '
        Me.PictureBox5.Image = Global.AssistenteFdF.My.Resources.Resources.tez
        Me.PictureBox5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(216, 81)
        Me.PictureBox5.Name = "PictureBox5"
        Me.PictureBox5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(57, 61)
        Me.PictureBox5.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        Me.PictureBox5.TabIndex = 3
        Me.PictureBox5.TabStop = False
        Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.PictureBox5, "Perguntas e respostas frequentes")
        '
        'PictureBox4
        '
        Me.PictureBox4.Image = Global.AssistenteFdF.My.Resources.Resources.metroui_other_mail_icon
        Me.PictureBox4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(142, 81)
        Me.PictureBox4.Name = "PictureBox4"
        Me.PictureBox4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(57, 61)
        Me.PictureBox4.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        Me.PictureBox4.TabIndex = 2
        Me.PictureBox4.TabStop = False
        Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.PictureBox4, "Enviar MP de advertência")
        '
        'PictureBox2
        '
        Me.PictureBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.PictureBox2.Image = Global.AssistenteFdF.My.Resources.Resources.icon_help
        Me.PictureBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(62, 81)
        Me.PictureBox2.Name = "PictureBox2"
        Me.PictureBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(57, 61)
        Me.PictureBox2.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        Me.PictureBox2.TabIndex = 1
        Me.PictureBox2.TabStop = False
        Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.PictureBox2, "Mensagens moderativas")
        '
        'bemvindo
        '
        Me.bemvindo.AutoSize = True
        Me.bemvindo.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial Narrow", 14.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.bemvindo.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(32, 10)
        Me.bemvindo.Name = "bemvindo"
        Me.bemvindo.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(516, 23)
        Me.bemvindo.TabIndex = 0
        Me.bemvindo.Text = "Bem-vindo ao assistente de moderação do fórum de suporte Forumeiros!" & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)
        '
        'ToolTip1
        '
        Me.ToolTip1.AutomaticDelay = 0
        Me.ToolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000
        Me.ToolTip1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
        Me.ToolTip1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
        Me.ToolTip1.InitialDelay = 0
        Me.ToolTip1.IsBalloon = True
        Me.ToolTip1.ReshowDelay = 100
        Me.ToolTip1.UseAnimation = False
        Me.ToolTip1.UseFading = False
        '
        'ErrorProvider1
        '
        Me.ErrorProvider1.ContainerControl = Me
        '
        'Label8
        '
        Me.Label8.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label8.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label8.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 294)
        Me.Label8.Name = "Label8"
        Me.Label8.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(131, 14)
        Me.Label8.TabIndex = 16
        Me.Label8.Text = "Verificar por atualizações" & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(575, 357)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.body)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.header)
        Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.header.ResumeLayout(False)
        CType(Me.PictureBox10, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox8, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox3, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.body.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.body.PerformLayout()
        CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox9, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox7, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox6, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox5, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox4, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox2, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.ErrorProvider1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents header As System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    Friend WithEvents body As System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    Friend WithEvents bemvindo As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox2 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents ToolTip1 As System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox4 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox5 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox6 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox7 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents Label2 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents Label3 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents Label5 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents Label4 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox9 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents Label6 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents Label7 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents ErrorProvider1 As System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox3 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox8 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox10 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents Label8 As System.Windows.Forms.Label

End Class
```

Comment: Acho que pela sua (esqueci o nome, aquela barra onde tem o fecha e minimizar) estar diferente, ou seja uma criada por você não tem a propriedade de mover, é isso ?

Comment: Coloque detalhes de como está feito. Dê informações que seja possível avaliarmos o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Exato Roberto, eu retirei ela para poder personalizar, e agora não tenho essa propriedade.

Comment: @bigown é basicamente o facto de eu ter personalizado a barra e agora não ter a propriedade

Comment: Já vi uma forma de fazer isso, mas faz tempo e eu lembro q era complicada.

Comment: Como eu faço para responder aqui ? (achei um codigo)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SZcreAwe , não tive tempo de testar, mas acho que vai funcionar.

Comment: E coloco esse código onde? No header?

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: Eu usei este código uma vez e funcionou 100%: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1592899/1274092. A única coisa é que ele está em C# e você precisará traduzir para VB. E ele move quando você clica numa área do formulário; então talvez você queira usar o evendo *MouseDown* de outro componente em vez de usar o do formulário.

Comment: A coisa é que sou iniciante em VB.net. E não consigo traduzir isso, mas agradeço a sua ajuda.

Comment: @MaradinhoPH Posso traduzir para você se reabrirem a pergunta. Você teria que mostrar como você desenvolveu esta barra de títulos fictícia, talvez colando o código de design do formulário (arquivo *"NomeFormulario.Designer.vb"*; senão eu posso fazer de um jeito que não funciona pra você e você não saberá adaptar.

Comment: Feito! Pergunta editada.

Comment: Agora só falta uma boa alma reabrir a pergunta.

Comment: Ficarei no aguardo ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisará transferir as mensagens de arrastar recebida pelo componente que substitui visualmente a barra de títulos para a barra de títulos real que você ocultou. Para tanto, você pode:

> Utilizar a API do Windows, importando a biblioteca nativa *user32.dll*.

Na prática, você encaminha para a barra de títulos a mensagem de que o mouse foi clicado nela, então as próximas mensagens (de arrastar e soltar) também serão enviadas para a barra de títulos.

O código final fica assim:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &HA1
    Private Const HT_CAPTION As Integer = &H2

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As Integer, wParam As Integer, lParam As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function ReleaseCapture() As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Sub PictureBox3_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.MouseDown

        DelegaArrastarParaBarraTitulo(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub header_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles header.MouseDown

        DelegaArrastarParaBarraTitulo(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DelegaArrastarParaBarraTitulo(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            ReleaseCapture()
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0)
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Notei que você um painel para representar visualmente a barra de títulos que você ocultou, e sobre este painel você colou uma imagem (*PictureBox*) exibindo o título "Assistente de Moderação".

Então por isso eu associei código ao evento *MouseDown* destes dois componentes.

*PictureBox3_MouseDown* e *header_MouseDown* são métodos associados aos respectivos eventos dos respectivos componentes.

<sub>O código desta resposta foi adatado desta outra resposta em C#: [Make a borderless form movable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/make-a-borderless-form-movable/1592899#1592899).</sub>

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8oixah - Deu esses 2 erros. Poderia ver se apliquei o código corretamente?  http://pastebin.com/jv5k2Azt

Comment: Atualizei a resposta incluindo o conector de linhas (espaço + underline) ao final da declaração de cada atributo: `<DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")> _`. Faça isso e verifique. A documentação diz que o atributo e o elemento que ele decora devem estar na mesma linha ou conectados pelo underline. Eu e você devemos estar usando versões diferentes do compilador, sendo o meu mais esperto e percebendo que o elemento está na próxima linha sem precisar conectar as linhas.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado pelo seu suporte e dedicação à minha questão, fico bastante grato. :)

Comment: @MaradinhoPH Você foi infeliz com a primeira versão da sua pergunta, que não tinha informações suficientes, mas se mostrou bastante interessado e forneceu tudo que lhe foi pedido para que você pudesse obter a solução. Você também dedicou-se - estamos quites :D